# Why can't you build a website in release mode?

Tags: asp.net, configuration, build

In ASP.Net, if I set up a **web application** I can configure it to be in **release mode** but with a **website** I can only set the configuration to be in **debug mode**. Why is this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In web site projects each page is compiled dynamically upon first request.  It will compile without debugging symbols unless you specify otherwise in the config file.

Comment: "each page is compiled dynamically for each page."  Do you mean each page is compiled per REQUEST?

Comment: Thanks Outlaw...fixed the grammar.

Answer (score 5):

A Web Site's debug/release is controlled by the Web.Config file:

```
<system.web>
  ...
  <compilation debug="true">
  ...
  </compilation>
</system.web>
```

Set debug="true" for debugging, set debug="false" for release.

Comment: no this doesnt change publish mode. they are different

Comment: This actually works, making a smaller output file when you "Publish Web App."

Answer (score 2):

Probably because a Web Application compiles the whole website into one DLL.  To run and debug pages requires recompiling the entire application.  Whereas a website project compiles dynamically at the page level.

Answer (score 0):

For websites one releases the source code to the site, there is no build to be done.

The code is built on site.